# Determine the number of elements of order 2 in AR

Tags: group-theory

[image]

So i have completed parts a and b. For b i reduced R to smith normal form and ended up with diagonals 1,2,6. From this i have said that the structure of the group is $Z_2 \oplus Z_6 \oplus Z$. But i have no idea what so ever about part c.

Comment: Hmmm... "[30 marks]"?

Comment: the 30 marks is the whole question. But this is revision for an exam i have tomorrow and this questions has a high chance of coming up. So want to be able to complete it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: No problem. I have been searching a while but only found explanations for subgroups of order n.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}$, only the identity element has finite order.  So any element of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}$ with finite order must be in the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_6 \times \langle \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}} \rangle$ (which is a finite group).

Comment: so how would you determine the number of elements of order 2?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to go through the $12$ elements in the subgroup and calculate their orders.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, let us focus on $\,\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_6\,$ , which for simplicity (for me, at least) we'll better write multiplicatively as $\,C_2\times C_6=\langle a\rangle\times\langle b\rangle\,\;,\;\;a^2=b^6=1$

Suppose the first coordinate is $\,1\,$ , then the second one *has* to have order $\,2\,$ , and the only option is $\,(1,b^3)\,$ , so we go over elements with non-trivial first coordinate, and thus the second coordinate has to have order dividing two:

$$(a,1)\;,\;\;(a,b^3)$$

and that seems to be pretty much all there is: three involutions as any such one either has first coordinate trivial or not...